# Magento Set Up Currency Conversion

Tags: magento-1.7

The store Base currency is in CAD$, and allowed currency is $USD. Custemers can see prices on store front in Both currenceis but when checkout credit card/paypal are charged in CAD$, since it base.

The issue arrises when customers chooses USD$ and goes to checkout, right until the last step they see the following:

```
Subtotal: USD $100
Shipping: USD $5
Grand Total: USD $105
**Your Credit card will be charged **CAD$140**
```

What is the best way to go around this issue **Your Credit card will be charged **CAD$140** since its misleading, customer was shopping in USD and now they get charged in CAD$

**I would like to make it so the moment customers go to checkout their USD prices are converted to CAD and either show BOTH values in the checkout or only show CAD$ as the only value, exclude the USD$.**

**The another issue, if customer checkout out in USD$ and their card/paypal get charged in CAD$. The invoice generated in Magento are still in USD$ and do not mention anywhere about original CAD$ charge towards credit card.**

For example, when  you shop on Shopify in currency **other than base**, once you click checkout all prices are mentioned in the base currency.

Comment: It might be a bit confusing for your customers if the currency suddenly changes? Are you saying your payment gateway doesn't allow USD transactions?

Comment: For example, when you shop on Shopify in currency other than base, once you click checkout all prices are mentioned in the base currency. I guess it makes sense. The problem with how Magento works is when customer checks out in US the INVOICES that I generate in Magnto show in USD$ without any mention about Credit Card will be Chard 140 CAD$

Comment: I have PayPal, so unless I use some magento extension that overwrites the base currency function and actually charges customers in USD$ (non base).  I dont know how to work around this issue

Comment: Have a look at this extension: https://github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento . Doesn't that tick all your boxes?

Comment: As a workaround to charge USD when customer chooses USD, it makes sense. But "How to remove the Your Credit card will be charged for" message in the checkout and sales emails? Even on screenshots the message is there.

Comment: in `app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml` you have a condition on `needDisplayBaseGrandtotal`, if you comment out the whole block, it won't show anymore. (the function is defined in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Totals.php` and only returns true if the base currency is different from the current one)

Comment: If I comment out conditon on "needDisplayBaseGrandtotal", your card will be charged will NOT show in checkout and sales emails correct?

Comment: That's correct @Icon - Added my response so we don't end up flooding the comment section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this extension: github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento, this will allow you to take Paypal transactions on different currencies.

If you want to hide the note saying customers will be charged in a different currency, open `app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/template/checkout/onep‌​age/review/totals.ph‌​tml` you have a condition on `needDisplayBaseGrandtotal`, if you comment out the whole block, it won't show anymore. (the function is defined in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Totals.php` and only returns true if the base currency is different from the current one)